# Sublime Text Go to Definition (Javascript)

Tags: sublimetext

I use Sublime Text 4 for Javascript and I have installed LSP-Typescript. The "Goto definition" does not work for variables that are defined in a different javascript file. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a project set up with all the required directories in it?

Comment: I have a project set up with "path": "." but it still not works. Am I doing something wrong?